# Python parsing many word documents

Tags: python, windows, ms-word

I wrote a small program which extract data from a word document and process it. The tool runs only on Windows (XP) and uses the PyWin32 Library.

Everything works but sometimes I have the following problems, which is quite annoying for the user.

1) I hide Word with this code but sometimes Word opens nevertheless and opens all the documents. This happens very unreliable and I can not find out why this happens. Does anybody notice the same problem?

```
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = False
```

2) After the program is used a couple of times with several hundreds of documents, the program crashes because of not enough RAM. Does anybody has a suggestion how I can handle this problem?

Edit: I'm loading the files like this:

```
def convert_word_to_text(path, id):
"""Converts the word documents in text format."""

    word.Documents.Open(path)
    doc = word.ActiveDocument
    table = doc.Tables(1)
    # Process the data

for file in files:
    convert_word_to_text(file, id)
```

Any help is very appreciated!
Stefanie

Answer (score 2):

Since you open a document:

```
word.Documents.Open(path)
doc
```

You should also close it. Something like this:

```
doc.close()
```

at the end of the function `convert_word_to_text` may help.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I only quit the application (word.Application.Quit(-1)) but do not close the file. I'll try this. Did you ever have problems with first issue?

Answer (score 1):

For (2), my guess is that you are loading a number of files into memory and then processing them. Instead, you should use a generator or for loop, load each file individually, extract text / whatever and then move on to the next file.  This kind of issue seems to often occur when loading external XML or binary-ish files (e.g., images with `PIL`, excel files with `openpyxl`, etc.).

Comment: I added snippet how I open and process the files. Is this the correct way?

Comment: @snowflake, that's fine, just make sure you return text (i.e., a big string or list of strings) rather than `doc` or `table`. To be clear, I've never used `PyWin32`.

Comment: Actually I take the data from the table and create a new plain text file and continue with this text file (not sure whether it is important to mention).

Comment: @snowflake I'm not really clear what that means, but if you're having memory issues, try to push everything towards python primitives (strings, integers, lists, etc.)